# Redefinition of 'operator=='

Tags: c++

I would like to understand why I get this operator redefinition error and why compiler tries to instantiate `ft::Viterator<const int>` when I am only declaring a `ft::vector<int>` in my main

```
In file included from mainconstit.cpp:3:
./vector.hpp:35:16: error: redefinition of 'operator=='
                        friend bool     operator==(Viterator<T1> const &lhs, Viterator<T2> const &rhs) { return (lhs.ptr == rhs.ptr); }
                                        ^
./vector.hpp:208:23: note: in instantiation of template class 'ft::Viterator<const int>' requested here
                                for(iterator it = this->begin(); it != this->end(); it++)
                                                  ^
./vector.hpp:127:162: note: in instantiation of member function 'ft::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::assign' requested here
                        vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()) : _alloc(alloc), _begin(NULL), _size(0), _capacity(0) { this->assign(first, last); }
                                                                                                                                                                                      ^
mainconstit.cpp:10:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'ft::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector<int>' requested here
        vector<int> v(4, 100);
                    ^
./vector.hpp:35:16: note: previous definition is here
                        friend bool     operator==(Viterator<T1> const &lhs, Viterator<T2> const &rhs) { return (lhs.ptr == rhs.ptr); }
                                        ^
```

with this code :

```
#ifndef VECTOR_HPP
# define VECTOR_HPP

/*...*/

namespace ft
{
    template<class T>
    class Viterator : public ft::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>
    {
        public:

/*...*/

            Viterator() : ptr(NULL) {}
            Viterator(Viterator const & src) : ptr(src.ptr) {}
            Viterator(pointer ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
            virtual ~Viterator() {}

            operator Viterator<T const>() const { return (Viterator<T const>(this->ptr)); }

            Viterator & operator=(Viterator const & rhs) {
                this->ptr = rhs.ptr;
                return (*this);
            }

            template<class T1, class T2>
            friend bool operator==(Viterator<T1> const &lhs, Viterator<T2> const &rhs) { return (lhs.ptr == rhs.ptr); }

            template<class T1, class T2>
            friend bool operator!=(Viterator<T1> const &lhs, Viterator<T2> const &rhs) { return (lhs.ptr != rhs.ptr); }

/*...*/
        private:
            pointer ptr;
    };

    template<class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T> >
    class vector
    {
        public:
/*...*/         

            explicit vector(const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()) : _alloc(alloc), _begin(NULL), _size(0), _capacity(0) {}
            explicit vector(size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(), const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()) : _alloc(alloc), _begin(NULL), _size(0), _capacity(0) { this->assign(n, val); }
            template<class InputIterator>
            vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type(), typename ft::enable_if<!ft::is_integral<InputIterator>::value>::type* = NULL) : _alloc(alloc), _begin(NULL), _size(0), _capacity(0) { this->assign(first, last); }
            vector(const vector& x) : _begin(NULL), _size(0), _capacity(0) { *this = x; }
            ~vector() { this->_alloc.deallocate(this->_begin, this->_capacity); }

            vector& operator=(const vector& x) {
                this->assign(x.begin(), x.end());
                return (*this);
            }

            iterator begin() { return (iterator(this->_begin)); }
            const_iterator begin() const { return (const_iterator(this->_begin)); }
            iterator end() { return (iterator(this->_begin + this->_size)); }
            const_iterator end() const { return (const_iterator(this->_begin + this->_size)); }
/*...*/
            template<class InputIterator>
            void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, typename ft::enable_if<!ft::is_integral<InputIterator>::value>::type* = NULL) {
                this->resize(0);
                this->resize(static_cast<size_type>(last - first));
                InputIterator it2 = first;
                for(iterator it1 = this->begin(); it2 != last; it1++)
                {
                    this->_alloc.construct(&(*it1), *it2);
                    it2++;
                }
            }
            void assign(size_type n, const value_type& val) {
                this->resize(0);
                this->resize(n);
                for(iterator it = this->begin(); it != this->end(); it++)
                    this->_alloc.construct(&(*it), val);
            }
/*...*/

        private:
            allocator_type  _alloc;
            pointer         _begin;
            size_type       _size;
            size_type       _capacity;
    };
}

#endif
```

Comment: I'll bet you could remove 95% of that code and still show the problem. And once you've cut out the deadwood, you might see the problem for yourself.

Comment: @S.M. Default `operator==` and `!=` can only compare objects of the same type, unlike the ones OP defined. *"You can't define operators as free functions inside the class."* You can, and often should.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a `friend` function inside of a class places it into the enclosing namespace. If that class is a template, a new function is generated for every instantiation.

Instantiating `Viterator` twice with different template arguments produces two copies of `operator==` and `operator!=`, with the exact same signatures, hence the error.

Possible solutions are:

- Define the operators outside of the class. If needed, you can *declare* them as `friend`s (as opposed to *define*).
- Make the operators non-template, with `Viterator<T>` parameters (causing the operators produced by different instantiations to have different signatures, removing the error). This stops you from comparing iterators with different template arguments, which may or may not be good.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten your example significantly to still get the point across:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
    T * ptr = nullptr;

    // problem: defined in each Foo instantiation
    template <typename X, typename Y>
    bool friend operator==(Foo<X> const& left, Foo<Y> const& right) {
        return left.ptr == right.ptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo<int> fint;
    Foo<char> fchar;
}
```

The problem is that the friend function is itself a template and it isn't tied to the containing class, but is defined in the containing class.  Yet friend functions are not actually class members, but are free-standing functions.  So we get multiple competing definitions in the same namespace when 2 or more `Foo<>` types are instantiated.

If you move the definition outside of the class, then it's only defined once:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
    T* ptr;

    template <typename X, typename Y>
    bool friend operator==(Foo<X> const& left, Foo<Y> const& right);
};

template <typename X, typename Y>
bool operator==(Foo<X> const& left, Foo<Y> const& right) {
    return left.ptr == right.ptr;
}
```

And the different Foo instantiations merely declare it as a friend, but do not define it.

But stepping back, why do this?  Do you really need to compare `Foo<int>` with `Foo<char>`?  The pointer comparison won't compile anyway, due to mismatching types.  The only case I can think of for 2 template parameters for this comparison is if T and U were base/derived class types, but even then it seems kind of nonsensical.

So remove the template from the function, and then you could also do this:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
    T* ptr;

    bool friend operator==(Foo<T> const& left, Foo<T> const& right) {
        return left.ptr == right.ptr;
    }
};
```

Notice, now the friend is definining only a single type of comparison, between two `Foo<T>`, and the parameter is decided by the containing class.  So now two instantiations of foo will produce *overloads* of operator==, not competing identical definitions.

I also would mention that in c++20 you can avoid the boilerplate definition, and have the compiler generate it for you with `= default` in place of the function body.

Comment: Just a question, out of curiosity! Why needs to be a `friend` function? What property does that add?

Comment: It allows the function to see the private member `Foo<T>::ptr`.

Comment: Friend alllows it to be a 2-argument function and access private data.  For regular member fucntions, the left hand side would be the implicit "this" parameter. Function lookup behaves differently between members and free functions, including the "hidden friend" technique, which can reduce the size of the overload set andspeed up compile times especially for common operator overloads, like `operator<<`.  In some generated JSON code, with many hundreds of overloads and thousands of calls it took minutes to compile time, but using hidden friends helped (in part) reduce it to 20 seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! And sorry for my unshortened code, I'm new to stack overflow.
To answer your question, I am doing this to be able to compare iterator and const_iterator (Viterator<T> and Viterator<const T>)
But there is still something that I don't understand, why in my example, the compiler is trying to instantiate a ft::Viterator<const int> ?